# Compare List of Nullable Values

Tags: c#

I have the following method to check if `values1` crossed above `values2`:

```
Boolean CrossAbove<T>(IList<T> values1, IList<T> values2) where T : IComparable {

  return values1[values1.Count - 2].CompareTo(values2[values2.Count - 2]) < 0 && values1.Last().CompareTo(values2.Last()) > 0;

}
```

So I might use something like:

```
List<Decimal> values1 = getValues1();
List<Decimal> values2 = getValues2();

Boolean result = CrossAbove(values1, values2);
```

But I need to pass nullable values. For example, using `Decimal?` in `values1`:

```
List<Decimal?> values1 = getValues1();
List<Decimal> values2 = getValues2();

Boolean result = CrossAbove(values1, values2);
```

When comparing and one of the values is null then return false ...

How to change the `CrossAbove` method to allow this?

**Update**

I ended up with the following which allows to use one argument as nullable and another as not nullable. Or both nullables or not nullables:

```
Boolean CrossAbove<T>(IList<Nullable<T>> values1, IList<Nullable<T>> values2) where T : struct, IComparable {

  if (values1[values1.Count - 2] == null || values1.Last() == null || values2[values1.Count - 2] == null || values2.Last() == null)
    return false;

  return values1[values1.Count - 2].Value.CompareTo(values2[values2.Count - 2].Value) < 0 && values1.Last().Value.CompareTo(values2.Last().Value) > 0;

} 

Boolean CrossAbove<T>(IList<Nullable<T>> values1, IList<T> values2) where T : struct, IComparable => CrossAbove(values1, values2.Select(x => new Nullable<T>(x)).ToList());

Boolean CrossAbove<T>(IList<T> values1, IList<Nullable<T>> values2) where T : struct, IComparable => CrossAbove(values1.Select(x => new Nullable<T>(x)).ToList(), values2);

Boolean CrossAbove<T>(IList<T> values1, IList<T> values2) where T : struct, IComparable => CrossAbove(values1.Select(x => new Nullable<T>(x)).ToList(), values2.Select(x => new Nullable<T>(x)).ToList());
```

I couldn't find a better way to do this and satisfy the requirements.

Any though?

Comment: The thing is `Nullable<T>` doesn't implement `IComparable`

Comment: Can this be done with nullable generics without using IComparable?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your method to receive the comparison logic, something like:

```
bool CrossAbove<T>(IList<T> values1, IList<T> values2, Func<T, T, int> compare)
{
     return compare(values1[values1.Count - 2], values2[values2.Count - 2]) < 0 && compare(values1.Last(), values2.Last()) > 0;
}
```

Then, for your first example it would be:

```
CrossAbove(values1, values2, decimal.Compare);
```

For your `List<decimal?>` example call you can invoke your method with a `compare` like the following:

```
CrossAbove(values1, values2, (v1, v2) => {
    if (v1.HasValue && v2.HasValue) {
       return v1.Value.CompareTo(v2.Value);
    }
    return v1 == null && v2 == null;
});
```

Note that both lists must be a list of `Nullable<decimal>`. Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**:
I'd implement `CrossAbove` generic on two type arguments and keep receiving the comparison delegate:

```
bool CrossAbove<T1, T2>(IList<T1> values1, IList<T2> values2, Func<T1, T2, int> compare)
```

At the time of calling `CrossAbove` you'll know what `T1` and `T2` concrete types are and you can pass the correct comparison delegate. This is the way I'd go and I think it is shorter. An example with `decimal` and `decimal?` would be:

```
// Params: values1: List<decimal>, values2: List<decimal?>
CrossAbove(values1, values2, (x,y) => {
    if (y.HasValue) { return x.CompareTo(y.Value);}
    // Either give 1 or -1 depending on your logic.
    return 1;
});
```

Comment: I added an update to my question with the solution I am going with that allows more control over the comparativos of nulls. What do you think? Couldn't find a way to make the code shorter.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Nullable.Compare<T>` like this:

```
Boolean CrossAbove<T>(IList<T?> values1, IList<T?> values2) where T : struct
{
    return 
        !values1.Reverse().Take(2).Any(x => !x.HasValue) &&
        !values2.Reverse().Take(2).Any(x => !x.HasValue) &&
        Nullable.Compare<T>(values1[values1.Count - 2],values2[values2.Count - 2]) < 0 
        && Nullable.Compare<T>(values1.Last(), values2.Last()) > 0;
}
```

However it makes comparison based on `Nullable` comparison described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.compare?view=netframework-4.8) which is different than what you expected. But you can make a little modification of you want.

Comment: I added an update to my question with the solution I am going with that allows more control over the comparativos of nulls. What do you think? Couldn't find a way to make the code shorter.

Comment: @MiguelMoura there's nothing wrong with having overloads and shorter code is not always better.